# How to share TextArea Component in multiple SWF - Runtime Share Library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

How to share TextArea Component in multiple swf

say

lib.swf (has TextArea Componenet)

main.swf (Import TextArea Componenet from lib.swf)

section.swf (Import TextArea Componenet from lib.swf)

Thanks,

particle

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to share components.
What you can do is, load lib.swf into main.swf and section.swf.

For that ,you have a MovieLoader, to which you will have to pass the source argument as the relative path to lib.swf.

Thanks,
Neeraj